# Contact List Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a contact list script. The list function works fine.

What the function is supposed to do is take the argument name in. If the argument matches any of the first names, bill or steve, it is supposed to log the friend's contact information to the console and return it.

I attempted to do that in my search function, but it is not returning the expected values (contact information - more specifically, the phone number). I am assuming it is my approach and misunderstanding of the object constructor.

```
// Creating friends object
var friends = new Object();

// Adding friends with name, phone number
friends.bill = new Object();
// Giving data to Bill
friends.bill.firstName = "Bill";
friends.bill.lastName = "Gates";
friends.bill.number = "623523";
friends.bill.address = ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']

friends.steve = new Object();
// Givin data to Steve
friends.steve.firstName = "Steve";
friends.steve.lastName = "Jobs";
friends.steve.number = "73472"
friends.steve.address = ['1 Infinite Loop','Silicon Valley','CA','64326']

// Search function
var search = function(name) {
    for (var key in friends) {
        if(name === friends.name.firstName) {
           console.log(friends.name.number);
            return friends.name.number;
        }
    };    
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that Steve has some of Bill's information? (In the Steve section: `friends.bill.lastname="Jobs"`)

Comment: @BubbleHacker, good catch! I did not notice that. As expected, the program does not run correctly, though. The search function is not composed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. A "friend" is a property of the `friends` object/dictionary. `for(var key in friends)` iters amongst the name/key of the properties of the `friends` object (and assigns the `key` variable to these properties one after the other). To fetch a property/"friend" from `friends` using its key, you should use `friends[key]` (where key is a string).

Please not the difference between these examples:

```
var key = "james";
friends[key];     // Fetch the property with the key "james".
friends.key;      // Fetch the property with the key "key".
friends["james"]; // Fetch the property with the key "james".
friends.james;    // Fetch the property with the key "james".
```

Here is the solution to you problem:

```js
// Creating friends object
var friends = new Object();

// Adding friends with name, phone number
friends.bill = new Object();
// Giving data to Bill
friends.bill.firstName = "Bill";
friends.bill.lastName = "Gates";
friends.bill.number = "623523";
friends.bill.address = ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']

friends.steve = new Object();
// Givin data to Steve
friends.steve.firstName = "Steve";
friends.steve.lastName = "Jobs"; // Typo here: bill -> steve.
friends.steve.number = "73472"; // Same as above.
friends.steve.address = ['1 Infinite Loop','Silicon Valley','CA','64326']


// Printing out entries in friend object
var list = function(parameter){
for (var key in friends){
    console.log(key);

}
}

// Search function

var search = function(name){
  for (var key in friends){
    var friend = friends[key];
    if(name === friend.firstName){
      console.log(friend.number);
      return friend.number;
    }
  };
}

search("Steve");
```